# Hide/Show the formatter button input when the row is in edit mode -inlinenav jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to Show the formatter button input when the row is in edit mode and Hide the button when the row is in non-edit mode. My code,

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks.

**UPDATED ENTIRE CODE:**

jQuery.jqgrid v4.4.4 - I installed using NuGet package manager of visual studio 2015.

```
//Grid View for Program Management
$(function () {
    var Role = $("#hiddenRole").val();
    $("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/programGrid',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['id', 'Program', 'Unit', 'Active?', '<input type="button" style="display: inline-block; padding: 3px 12px;margin: 0px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;border-radius: 4px;overflow:visible;border:1px solid #444444;color: #000;box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px 0px #cccccc;" id="addNewProgramId" value="Add New Program" onclick= "addNewProgram()"/>'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
            {
                name: 'ProgramDesc', index: 'ProgramDesc', editable: true, width: "580px",
                editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: programDescValidation
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'UnitID', index: 'UnitID', editable: true, edittype: 'select', width: "200px",
                formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: "Unit1:Unit1 ; Unit2/3:Unit2/3" },
                editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: dupicateRecordValidation
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'InActive', index: 'InActive', editable: true, formatter: 'select', width: "200px",
                stype: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: "false:No;true:Yes" }
            },
            {             
                name: 'SaveChanges',               
                sortable: false, align: "center", classes: "button", width: "400px",
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObj) {                   
                    var cBtn = '<input type="button" id= "saveChangesId" value="Save Changes" onclick= "saveChanges(' + "'" + rowObj.id + "'" + '\)"/>'
                        return cBtn;

                }
            }
        ],
        //autoResizing: { compact: true },
        //autoResizable: true,
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 3,
        rowList: [3, 6, 9, 12],
        height: '100%',
        //shrinkToFit: false,
        //height: '300',
        width: '1328',
        //width: outerwidth,
        scrollerbar: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Program' + " " + Role,
        //loadonce: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        scrollerbar: false,
        //editurl: '/Home/programGridSave',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        hidegrid: false,
        //autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,       
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            rowSelect(id);
        },

    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, cancel: false, reload: false, refresh: false }) .jqGrid("gridResize"),
    $("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager',
        {
            edit: false, add: false, save: false, cancel: false, reload: false, refresh: false, restoreAfterSelect: false, 
        });
});
```

**CONTROLLER JSON RETURN METHOD:**

```
List<ProgramModel> programModelList = new List<ProgramModel>();
        ProgramModel programModel = new ProgramModel();
 public JsonResult programGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)  //Gets the todo Lists.
        {
            programModel.id = "001";
            programModel.ProgramDesc = "A";
            programModel.InActive = true;
            programModel.UnitID = "Unit1";
            programModelList.Add(programModel);

            programModel = new ProgramModel();
            programModel.id = "002";
            programModel.ProgramDesc = "B";
            programModel.InActive = true;
            programModel.UnitID = "Unit1";
            programModelList.Add(programModel);

            programModel = new ProgramModel();
            programModel.id = "003";
            programModel.ProgramDesc = "C";
            programModel.InActive = true;
            programModel.UnitID = "Unit2/3";
            programModelList.Add(programModel);

            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            var results = programModelList.Select(emp => new
            {
                emp.id,
                emp.InActive,
                emp.ProgramDesc,
                emp.UnitID,
            });
            int totalRecords = results.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
            {
                results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.id);
                results = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                results = results.OrderBy(s => s.id);
                results = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = results
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

CURRENT BEHAVIOUR:
[image]

Comment: Please, include **in all your questions** the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop free jqGrid fork, where I can mostly help. Some other minimal possibilities exist in all versions of jqGrid too. By the way, one can combine `inlineNav` with `formatter: "actions"`, which solves automatically the problem, which you try to solve in your current question.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your feedback. Combining "inlinenav" with formatter: "actions" is not working, kindly correct me if any mistake in code. Please find my updated code and version.

Comment: Some problems exist in retro version 4.4.4, which you use, in combination of `inlineNav` and `formatter: "actions"`. The problem is solved many years ago. You can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm), for example, that the buttons of `navGrid` and `formatter: "actions"` will be synchronized automatically.

Comment: @Oleg: As Combining "inlinenav" with formatter: "actions" is not working, Using input button ID I did show() and hide() property. It works but all the time button shown at the top row of the jqgrid when any row changed to editmode. Also, the button not shown for newly added row instead shown at the top row of the jqgrid. Please find the screenshot. Kindly suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Which jqGrid you use currently? Is your last comment concerns your old code or the code with `formatter: "actions"` and `inlineNav`? You can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) that "save" and "delete" buttons of `formatter: "actions"` and `inlineNav` will be hide **automatically** on start of editing and the "save" and "cancel" buttons will be visible. Both methods register jqGridInlineAfterRestoreRow jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow and jqGridInlineEditRow events and thus hiding/showing/disabling/enabling is really save and synchronous.

Comment: @Oleg: I'm using navGrid. As per my requirement i have created my own Add, Save buttons and calling the editRow, addRow, saveRow, restoreRow syntax inside my button function. Thats why your solution is not working for me. Please suggest me to resolve this my issue. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you made *bugs* in your new code or you skipped some important steps, which are required. I'm not sure why you need to define custom buttons, which do the same as the default buttons. In any way, you have to post **your current code** or the demo. I can't find the reason of your current problems if you don't see your current code. Moreover I asked you to include an example of the JSON response from `'/Home/programGrid'`. You can use Network tab of Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to see HTTP traffic. I suppose that you can reduce your JavaScript code essentially.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks a lot for your valuable time you spare for this question. Believe or not I'm waiting for your replies. As you suggested I have posted my entire code of JSON response and javascript for your reference. Please find the UPDATED ENTIRE CODE. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131412/discussion-between-kavitha-and-oleg).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to update from very old 4.4.4 version of jqGrid to free jqGrid 4.13.5 (or 4.13.6, which I will publish today). I recommend you additionally to use `formatter: "actions"` (or better `template: "actions"`) instead of the custom formatter, which you use currently. Both `formatter: "actions"` and `inlineNav` uses (in free jqGrid) the event `jqGridInlineEditRow` to hide/disable the buttons "save" and "delete" on start of inline editing and show/enable "save" and "cancel" instead. In the same `formatter: "actions"` and `inlineNav` register `jqGridInlineAfterRestoreRow` and  `jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow` events to switch from "save" and "cancel" buttons back to "save" and "delete" after end of editing. It's really safe way to hold the buttons of `formatter: "actions"` and `inlineNav` always synchronous.

If you want to understand how one could implement the custom formatter which do the same then you can modify the definition of the column with the custom formatter. You should take in consideration the following:

1. You current code contains **no `name`** property for the column with the button. It's a bug. The unique `name` property, which value corresponds `id` requirements of HTML (for example no spaces are allowed inside), is **required** for every item of `colModel`.
2. You use `class: "button"` in the last column, but you mean probably `classes` instead of `class` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). One can specify *multiple* classes divide by space. If you fix the property name to `classes`, then you will see `class="button"` attribute on `<td>` element, which contains the button. Thus you can remove `style` attribute of `'<input type="button" ... value="Save Changes"/>` and to move the inline CSS properties to the corresponding CSS rule instead

```css
.button input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: visible;
    border:1px solid #444444;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px 0px #cccccc;
}
```

1. You use currently `onclick= "saveChanges(' + "'" + rowObj.id + "'" + '\)"`. I'd recommend you to change the code of `onclick` to

```js
onclick="return saveChanges.call(this,event);"
```

where we initialize `this` of `saveChanges` to the button and forward `Event` object as the first parameter of global `saveChanges` function.

One can get all required Information and to find any elements *in the same `<td>` or `<tr>`* using relative operations. `var $td = $(this).closest("td");` or better `var $td = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow>td");` is the outer cell (jQuery wrapper to DOM element, which represents the cell). To get `<tr>` one can use `var $tr = $td.closest("tr");` or better `var $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow");`. One can use `var $tr = $td.parent();` if one used `var $td = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow>td");` before. To get `rowid` one can use just `var rowid = $tr.attr("id");` and so on. One can really use only relative paths.

The same do `formatter: "actions"` internally. Thus I recommend you to use it instead of doing the same with respect of custom formatters.